# meshes in blender vs. in unity

Tags: mesh, unity, .fbx

I'm trying to understand how the meshes are working in blender vs. unity.

My goal is to take an object with many meshes, and after applying the textures and the materials in blender, merge the meshes into one mesh using "join". Now, there's only one mesh for the object and I export a .fbx file.

In Unity however, after importing the .fbx file, the object has multiple meshes regardless the fact that in blender it had only one mesh.

Can anyone explain to me why unity avoid the mesh changes made in blender?

Comment: Note that joining multiple objects consisting of one ore more meshes into one object doesn't technically create one mesh in Blender. There still will be multiple meshes inside that object. Also vertex limit as mentioned in the answer etc apply as well

Comment: "Join" specifically merges mesh data, the two meshes aren't distinguishable in the single mesh data that it produces. Blender objects are only able to contain either 0 or 1 instance of mesh data. Boolean modifier, after being applied, also produces one mesh to the data of the object that the modifier was on. The other object that the modifier referenced will remain unchanged and will export as well if you did not check "Select objects" in the export settings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have "Selected objects" enabled when exporting the FBX file, otherwise all objects including hidden objects and objects on another layers get exported in the same file. Besides that the only explanation for multiple meshes per 1 exported mesh is exceeding Unity's 64,000 vertices per mesh limit that causes your mesh to import as multiple segments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mesh just has too many verts, Unity doesn't support those complex meshes and splits them up into multiple parts. could you include a picture? If you're going to make an object with many meshes, i also suggest you create the materials in unity.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue with the "Join" feature when trying export form Blender to Unity.

I used a Boolean modifier with the Union method to finalize to a single object before export. Check [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18337/how-can-i-preserve-both-materials-from-two-meshes-that-undergo-boolean-union) out for handling multiple materials with the Boolean op.

[image]