# Boolean object like texts transfer color to the object it is carved from?

Tags: modifiers

I am wanting to make 3D text and then cut this text with a Boolean difference  from an object but want the engraved letters to have color so they stand out. I really could not find much on this topic. I have seen some nice tutorials on how to make some cool 3D texts but nothing about how to stamp the other object with the text color after the Boolean operation.

Thanks again.

Comment: Seems like you didn't really search much at all. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34215/making-intersecting-parts-of-objects-turn-the-combined-colour-redblue-purple/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18337/how-can-i-preserve-both-materials-from-two-meshes-that-undergo-boolean-union or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/engraving-a-text-string-in-blender-internal-render or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/inscribing-text-into-an-object/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links. It appears that the second link addresses my question. Thanks for taking the time to research this out for me. I will give this a try.